# Hapi/Joi validation - different Joi.regex depending on another key value

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, joi

I have a scenario where I need to validate a vat number with different regex depending on which country it is. So when the field `language` is `SE` i want to use this regex `/^\d{6}-\d{4}$/` on the field `company.vatNo`, but when the field `language` is `NO` i want to use this one `/^\d{9}(MVA)?$/`.. I thought i could go with Joi's when(), but it doesnt seem to work at all. Does anybody know how i can achieve this?

Here's my route where i validate:

```
module.exports = {
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/signup/{partner}',
  handler: createPartner,
  config: {
    validate: {
      payload: {
        language: Joi.string().allow(config.supportedLanguages).required(),
        company: {
         vatNo: {

           Joi
           .when('language', {
             is: 'SE', 
             then: Joi.string().regex(/^\d{6}-\d{4}$/).required()
           })
           .when('language', {
             is: 'NO',
             then: Joi.string().regex(/^\d{9}(MVA)?$/).required()
           })
           .when('language', {
             is: 'FI',
             then: Joi.string().regex(/^\d{7}-\d{1}$/).required()
           })

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a `switch` to set the value of the regex based on language?

Comment: Where can i use a switch in this situation? @JaredSmith

Comment: You have access to the Accept-Language header, just put in a code that checks it and assigns the appropriate regex to a variable, which you then use to validate.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm using Hapijs validation in the route, so I have nowhere to do what you suggest before the validation runs. If I use a pre handler it will run after the validation. I mean, i can do what you suggest inside my handler, but then i need to do the validation inside the handler aswell.

Comment: Yeah, I use Hapi but validate by hand. OTOH, my use cases are limited enough that its acceptable to do it by hand, YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution. It seems like Joi doesn't recognize `language` if `vatNo` is inside another object. But this solved the problem:

```
    language: Joi.any().valid(config.supportedLanguages).required(),
    vatNo:
      Joi.alternatives()
        .when('language', {
          is: Joi.string().regex(/^(SE)$/i),
          then: Joi.string().regex(/^\d{6}-\d{4}$/).label('companyID')
        })
        .when('language', {
          is: Joi.string().regex(/^(NO)$/i),
          then: Joi.string().regex(/^\d{9}(MVA)?$/).label('companyID')
        })
        .when('language', {
          is: Joi.string().regex(/^(FI)$/i),
          then: Joi.string().regex(/^\d{7}-\d{1}$/).label('companyID')
        }),
```